# My existing code is altered by adding a button

Tags: button, basic

If I add a new button to a VB windows form, all the existing buttons on that form, have part of the first line of their code wiped, as shown in italics below.

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) ***Handles Button1.Click***

I then have to go through line by line, manually replacing the missing code.
Why is this happening?

It happens on placing the button, before any code is attached. Dragging any type of button to the form has the same effect.

Comment: What VB are we talking about? VB6 or VB.NET? Adding the appropriate tag instead of the very generic [tag:basic] tag, might help attracting people with the relevant knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Reading another forum, it appears I've been using and earlier version of Visual Studio, where this is a known issue. Updated and  all ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).